# How do I change the value of this component everytime I pass it in? ES6, reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a component call 'sectionlabel' that I pass into my different profile pages.  I just want to be able to change the value of it for each section.

```
import React from 'react';


class ProfileSectionLabel extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return <div className="profile-bar-header" value></div>;
    }

};

export default ProfileSectionLabel;
```

And when I import it I guess I want to do something like

```
<ProfileSectionLabel value='account'/>
```

I guess since it's not a form, it'd be better to use text or name ??

Comment: What the `value` placed as a `div` attribute means?

Comment: the text value.  So the end result would be something like <div> This the section name</div>

Comment: So it must be **between** `<div>` and `</div>` then

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic stuff, please read a [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) or look at existing components.

```
return <div className="profile-bar-header">{this.props.value}</div>;
```